# How to use multiple threads to efficiently run the topological sort?

Tags: multithreading, topological-sort

[image]

How do I run the topological sort efficiently for this graph using threads. I welcome and appreciate your thoughts.

Can we split the process on node 13 (sharing 3 threads) ? If so, how do we do it ?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you find zero dependencies on the vertex, assign that (vertex) to thread/process. This process will continue until you finish all the vertex.

For maintaining a thread, you can take a thread pool.

You can read more about scheduling algorithms as well.

That's it.

source:-

- https://medium.com/@TRikace/parallelizing-tasks-with-dependencies-design-your-code-to-optimize-performance-d0948549f1eb
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7T-gjX24FR0